# Class separation from scatterplot visualisation

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

[image]

Above is the image I got after using

```
plt.scatter(x[feature1],x[classes],c=x[classes])
```

Now, it appears to me (novice) that the classes are well separated by this `feature1`.

On applying a RF classifier I get approx 55% accuracy ,noting that total classes are 7 , hence the prediction accuracy is above the random baseline, but I was confused if there is such a distinct seperation(supposedly) then why the results are not on similar terms?

Comment: Can you please verify if your question uses the most useful tags it would need to be read by the right people that could potentially answer it? Is it even suitable for Stackoverflow (as being about programming) or maybe rather some other site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, it appears to me (novice) that the classes are well separated by this `feature1`.

Are they? Let's try to see qualitatively, based on your plot...

For a good separation, we should have classes that *do not overlap* (or overlap minimally) in the given feature. The only classes that seem to exhibit this characteristic are classes 4 & 5, which have a relatively small overlap around 2500.

Let's take a value of 2750; according to your plot, the respective samples can be of class 1, 2, 3, 5, or 6.

Let's move a little higher, around 3000; the respective samples here can be of class 1, 2, 5, or 7.

Moving lower, around 2500 (the overlapping region of classes 4 & 5), it seems that the samples can be anything except class 7.

The only unambiguous separation seems to be for values greater than 3750 (class 7). Even the lowest values of the feature (< 2000) are shared between classes 3 and 6.

Viewing the big picture, it doesn't look like `feature1` on its own offers any exceptional separation between your 7 classes; apart from the areas around its minimum & maximum values, all other ranges are shared by at least 3-4 classes...